# How to manage showing data in recyclerView Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `webView` with three components that comes from `html` file. I want the app to send a sms after clicking the button and show message log in a `recyclerView`.

so the sms will be sent correctly but nothing show in`recyclerView`.

message.html in assets

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sendAndroidMessage() {

                phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
                messageText = document.getElementById('messageText').value;

                Android.sendMessage(phoneNumber, messageText);
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="phoneNumber" type="tel" placeholder="Enter the Phone Number"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input id="messageText" type="text" placeholder="Enter Message Content" >
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input id="sendBtn" type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendAndroidMessage()" >
    </body>
</html>
```

javaScriptInterface

```
    public SendMessageInterface(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String messageText) {

    message = new Message();
    message.setMessageText(messageText);
    message.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    sendSMS();
}
```

sendSMS():

```
String smsBody      = message.getMessageText();
        String phoneNumber  = message.getPhoneNumber();

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        context.registerReceiver (new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        message.setMessageSent(true);

                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:

                        message.setMessageSent(false);

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                        message.setMessageSent(false);

                        Toast.makeText(context, "No service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:

                        message.setMessageSent(false);

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                        message.setMessageSent(false);

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody, sentPI, deliveredPI);

        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and finally MainActivity.java :

```
messageInfo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    messageInfo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/message.html");
    messageInfo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    message = new Message();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.show_message);
    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messageList);

    messageInfo.addJavascriptInterface(new SendMessageInterface(MainActivity.this), "Android");

    setMessageAdapter();
```

setMassageAdapter():

```
messageList.add(message);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I'm so confused and have no idea how to fix it or search for what

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found the answer! I put it here hope to be useful for others.
No need to `asyncTask` class or anything, it just need call `setMessageAdapter` just when SMS have been sent. now `Mainctivity` is like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkPermission();


    messageInfo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    messageInfo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/message.html");
    messageInfo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    message = new Message();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.show_message);
    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messageList);

    messageInfo.addJavascriptInterface(new SendMessageInterface(), "Android");

}

public void checkPermission(){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};

            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
}

public class SendMessageInterface {

    public SendMessageInterface() {}
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String messageText) {

        message = new Message();
        message.setMessageText(messageText);
        message.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

        sendSMS();
    }
}

public void sendSMS(){

    String smsBody      = message.getMessageText();
    String phoneNumber  = message.getPhoneNumber();

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver (new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    message.setMessageSent(true);
                    Log.e("is sent?1", ": " + message.isMessageSent());
                    setMessageAdapter();
                default:
                    message.setMessageSent(false);
                    setMessageAdapter();
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody, sentPI, null);

        dataBase = new DataBase(MainActivity.this);
        dataBase.insertSms(phoneNumber, smsBody, message.isMessageSent());


    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,ex.getMessage().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void setMessageAdapter(){

    messageList.add(message);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```